# vscodevim normal mode key binding toggle terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I've been using vscodevim and I've been trying to remap the Ctrl+` command to toggle the terminal in normal mode, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my settings.json file.

```
{
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "vim.leader": "<space>",
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["k", "j"],
            "after": ["<Esc>"]
        },
    ],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["<leader>", "f"],
            "after": ["<C-`>"]

        }
    ],

    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
}
```

Here's my keybindings.json file if you need it.

```
[
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "tab",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+tab",
        "command": "outdent",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus"
    },
]
```